# Angular2 routes with different templates

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

Maybe I'm not understanding the concept that is required so if there's already an answer or tutorial, just point me in that direction and I'll look into there...

I'm creating an Angular 2 webapp and I'm having difficulty understanding the best way to set things up so that I have a particular view while authenticated vs. when not authenticated.

I originally created many pages all from a component that housed four components: header, side navigation bar, body, footer. However, the contents of header, side navigation bar, body, and footer should only really be available to users who are authenticated, and when I tried to create a new component (i.e. a login component that should come before the other components) it keeps going into the area of the body component. This makes sense to me, from my understanding of the router-outlet, I just don't know how to separate the two areas of my app (authenticated views vs non authenticated views).

I'm reading up on Route Guards which will help me direct traffic accordingly. The bigger question for me is now that I want to implement authentication, and because I expect to have different template layouts between authenticated and non authenticated views, is there something other than guards that I need to be researching to help route the users properly and display the content appropriately? Is there aspects of Angular2's router that I should be reading to make sure I'm not missing a part of the setup?

Just as a quick example for discussion, here's a layout of how I would want the site to behave (it's not a directory structure, just more of a conceptual layout). Again, authenticated views have the header/navbar/body/footer layout where the non-authenticated view wouldn't have that, it would just be a simple page:

1. Authenticated Views:

   - Dashboard
   - User Profile
2. Non Authenticated Views:

   - Login Window

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.